# Create a MultiIndexed DataFrame from a DataFrame with dict values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python Pandas DataFrame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'o': [{'ask':1, 'bid':2},{'ask':3, 'bid':4}], 'h': [{'ask':5, 'bid':6},{'ask':7, 'bid':8}]})

                        h                       o
0  {u'ask': 5, u'bid': 6}  {u'ask': 1, u'bid': 2}
1  {u'ask': 7, u'bid': 8}  {u'ask': 3, u'bid': 4}
```

I would like to create a MultiIndexed DataFrame (hierachical columns - first level being ask/bid)

Answer (score 0):

one possibility:

```
>>> df
                      h                     o
0  {'bid': 6, 'ask': 5}  {'bid': 2, 'ask': 1}
1  {'bid': 8, 'ask': 7}  {'bid': 4, 'ask': 3}
>>> d = df.to_dict()
>>> pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, d.values())), keys=list(d.keys())).T
    h       o    
  ask bid ask bid
0   5   6   1   2
1   7   8   3   4
```

Comment: I don't think that converting to list is a good idea because of performance issue. Moreover I was looking for ask/bid as first level.